# Android Login with Database SQLite not working correctly

Tags: database, sqlite, authentication

I am creating a login page with SQLite but it is not working correctly. Whenever I run my project it does not show any error and installs apk successfully, but query portion is showing errors in both queries and I am unable to find any kind of error in my queries. I am posting DB helper class. please someone guide me so that I could be able to find the error and fix it.

```
    package com.example.u.database;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import com.example.u.entities.Accounts;

public class AccountsDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String dbName= "accountDB";
    private static String tableName= "account";
    private static String idColumn= "id";
    private static String usernameColumn= "username";
    private static String passwordColumn= "password";
    private static String fullameColumn= "fullname";
    private static String emailColumn= "email";

    public AccountsDB(Context context){
        super(context, dbName, null, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table" + tableName + "(" +
                idColumn + "integer primary key autoincrement," +
                usernameColumn + "text, " +
                passwordColumn + "text, " +
                fullameColumn + "text," +
                emailColumn + "text" +
                ")" );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean create(Accounts accounts){
        boolean result= true;
        try {
            SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues contentValues= new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(usernameColumn, accounts.getUsername());
            contentValues.put(passwordColumn, accounts.getPassword());
            contentValues.put(fullameColumn, accounts.getFullname());
            contentValues.put(emailColumn, accounts.getEmail());
            result= sqLiteDatabase.insert(tableName, null, contentValues) > 0;

        }catch (Exception e){
            result= false;
        }
        return result;
    }
    public static Accounts login(String username, String password){
        Accounts accounts= null;
        try {
            SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase= getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor= sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("select * from" + tableName +
                    "where username= ? and password = ?", new String[] {username, password});
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
                accounts= new Accounts();
                accounts.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
                accounts.setUsername(cursor.getString(1));
                accounts.setPassword(cursor.getString(2));
                accounts.setFullname(cursor.getString(3));
                accounts.setEmail(cursor.getString(4));
            }

        }catch (Exception e){
            accounts = null;
        }
        return accounts;
    }
    public Accounts checkUsername (String username){
        Accounts accounts= null;
        try {
            SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase= getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor= sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("select * from" + tableName +
                    "where username= ?", new String[] {username});
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
                accounts= new Accounts();
                accounts.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
                accounts.setUsername(cursor.getString(1));
                accounts.setPassword(cursor.getString(2));
                accounts.setFullname(cursor.getString(3));
                accounts.setEmail(cursor.getString(4));
            }

        }catch (Exception e){
            accounts = null;
        }
        return accounts;
    }
}
```

Please help me to find erroe in my code so I am able to complete my project

Answer (score 0):

You have omitted spaces after identifiers (table and column names) try the following :-

```
db.execSQL("create table " + tableName + "(" +
                idColumn + " integer primary key," +
                usernameColumn + " text, " +
                passwordColumn + " text, " +
                fullameColumn + " text," +
                emailColumn + " text" +
                ")" );
```

- Note autoincrement keyword has been removed, it is highly likely you don't need it. [see SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html) which includes :-

> The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and
>   disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is
>   usually not needed.

**You will have to delete, the apps data or uninstall the app, after making the changes.**

- *as the database exists, albeit empty from your perspective, the **onCreate** method will not run*
- note your **onUpgrade** would fail if used as the call to **onCreate** would try to recreate the tables which already exist (you probably need to **DROP** the tables and then call **onCreate**)

Comment: Thnx a lot sir.... Now it is looking good.... But I've facing another problem. When I called getReadableDatabase in login Activity it shows an error and requires static approach. After making it static method getReadableDatabase in database class shows an error to make login non static 
this is the DB class statement:
`SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase= getReadableDatabase();`

This is the Login Activity statement:
`Accounts accounts= AccountsDB.login(uname, pass);`

Comment: **getReadableDatabase** is a method (not static) of **SQLiteOpenHelper** and as such requires an **SQLiteOpenHelper** object. Making the login method static means that it is a method for the AccountsDB class NOT an AccountsDB object (and thus an object based upon an SQLiteOpenHelper object) method. Therefore with static there is no defined SQLiteOpenHelper object. So you need to remove **static** from the **login** method. In the activity you need to instantiate an AccountsDB object e.g. `myAccountsDB = new AccountsDB(this);` and then use `myAccountsDB.login(the_uname_to_use,the_pass_to_use)`.